# Unable to use highcharts dark theme or system theme switcher for react native highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using : https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native

for my project here :
https://github.com/pgajbhiye/RNHighChartsApp

I am trying to replicate what is provided in this codepen here :
https://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/vstf68b3/
 
But i am not able to make it work for react native , can someone please help how i can do dark mode .

Would really appreicate your help.

Comment: Hi, can you show the styles file, how do you added dark mode? it seems to me that you have to load them manually for them to work, can you test it?

Comment: Documentation [highcharts-react-native#highcharts-chart](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native#highcharts-chart) provides a truncated example of how to load styles for container, classes are present like objects.

Answer (score 0):

I was to able to add theme using

````
const useDarkMode = colorScheme === 'dark';```
and then toggle highcharts style based on theme
````